# Android and draw routes in Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a small problem, I need to develop an application that shows the route of public transport, I found tutorials about route of cars.

I saw this example:http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=25.04202,121.534761&daddr=25.05202,121.554761&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml

and tried to add dirflg = & rB the URL to show the public transport but server responded with  the empty kml.

Does anyone know how to help me?

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you are asking this for android, you can use the following intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345")); startActivity(intent);
```

where saddr and daddr are starting and destination address's location coordinates.

same has been discussed in several threads already

Comment: That's not my question. My question is how to get the route using Google maps, but for bus

Comment: Do not answer my question. What I need is to get the Route from Google maps for public transport